# repeated measures bootstrap stats, grouped by multiple factors

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

I have a data frame that looks like this, but obviously with many more rows etc:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                 cond=c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'),
                 comm=c('X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y','X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y'),
                 measure=c(0.8, 1.1, 0.7, 1.2, 0.9, 2.3, 0.6, 1.1, 0.7, 1.3, 0.6, 1.5, 1.0, 2.1, 0.7, 1.2))
```

So we have 2 factors (each with 2 levels, thus 4 combinations) and one continuous measure. We also have a repeated measures design in that we have multiple `measure`'s within each cell that correspond to the same `id`.

I've attempted to first solve the `groupby` issue, then the bootstrap issue, then combine the two, but am pretty much stuck...

**Stats, grouped by the 2 factors**

I can get multiple summary stats for each of the 4 cells by:

```
summary_stats <- aggregate(df$measure, 
                           by = list(df$cond, df$comm),
                           function(x) c(mean = mean(x), median = median(x), sd = sd(x)))
print(summary_stats)
```

resulting in

```
  Group.1 Group.2     x.mean   x.median       x.sd
1       A       X 0.85000000 0.85000000 0.12909944
2       B       X 0.65000000 0.65000000 0.05773503
3       A       Y 1.70000000 1.70000000 0.58878406
4       B       Y 1.25000000 1.20000000 0.17320508
```

This is great as we are getting multiple stats for each of the 4 cells.

*But what I'd really like is the 95% bootstrap CI's, for each stat, for each of the 4 cells.* I don't mind if I have to run a final solution once for statistic (e.g. mean, median, etc), but bonus points for doing it all in one go.

**Bootstrap for repeated measures**

Can't quite make this work, but what I want is 95% bootstrap CI's, done in a way which is appropriate for this repeated measures design. Unless I'm mistaken then I want to select bootstrap samples on the basis of `id` (*not* on the basis of rows of the dataframe), then calculate a summary measure (e.g. `mean`) for each of the 4 cells.

```
library(boot)
myfunc <- function(data, indices) {
   # select bootstrap sample to index into `id`
   d <- data[data$id==indicies,]
   return(c(mean=mean(d), median=median(d), sd = sd(d)))
}

bresults <- boot(data = CO2$uptake, statistic = myfunc, R = 1000)
```

Q1: I'm getting errors in selecting the bootstrap sample by `id`, i.e. the line `d <- data[ data$id==indicies, ]`

**Combining bootstrap and the `groupby` 2 factors**

Q2: I have no intuition of how to gel the two approaches together to achieve the final desired result. My only idea is to put the `aggregate` call in `myfunc`, to repeatedly calculate cell stats under each bootstrap replicate, but I'm out of my comfort zone with R here.

Answer (score 4):

With your two questions, you have two issues:

1. How to bootstrap (resample) your data in such a way that you resample based on `id`, rather than rows
2. How to perform separate bootstraps for the four groups in your 2x2 design

One easy way to do this would be by using the following packages (all part of the [`tidyverse`](http://tidyverse.org/)):

- `dplyr` for manipulating your data (in particular, summarising the data you have for each `id`) and also for the neat `%>%` forward pipe operator which supplies the result of an expression as the first argument to the next expression so you can chain commands
- `broom` for doing an operation for each group in your dataframe
- `boot` (which you already use) for the bootstrapping

---

Load the packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(boot)
```

First of all, to make sure when we resample we include a subject or not, I would save the various values each subject has as a list:

```
df <- df %>%
    group_by(id, cond, comm) %>%
    summarise(measure=list(measure)) %>%
    ungroup()
```

Now the dataframe has fewer rows (4 per ID), and the variable `measure` is not numeric anymore (instead, it's a list). This means we can just use the indices that `boot` provides (solving issue 1), but also that we'll have to "`unlist`" it when we actually want to do calculations with it, so your function now becomes:

```
myfunc <- function(data, indices) {
    data <- data[indices,]
    return(c(mean=mean(unlist(data$measure)),
             median=median(unlist(data$measure)),
             sd = sd(unlist(data$measure))))
}
```

Now that we can simply use `boot` to resample each row, we can think about how to do it neatly per group. This is where the `broom` package comes in: you can ask it to `do` an operation for each group in your data frame, and store it in a `tidy` dataframe, with one row for each of your groups, and a column for the values that your function produces. So we simply group the dataframe again, and then call `do(tidy(...))`, with a `.` instead of the name of our variable. This hopefully solves issue 2 for you!

```
bootresults <- df %>%
    group_by(cond, comm) %>%
    do(tidy(boot(data = ., statistic = myfunc, R = 1000)))
```

This produces:

```
# Groups:   cond, comm [4]
     cond   comm   term  statistic         bias    std.error
   <fctr> <fctr>  <chr>      <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
 1      A      X   mean 0.85000000  0.000000000 5.280581e-17
 2      A      X median 0.85000000  0.000000000 5.652979e-17
 3      A      X     sd 0.12909944 -0.004704999 4.042676e-02
 4      A      Y   mean 1.70000000  0.000000000 1.067735e-16
 5      A      Y median 1.70000000  0.000000000 1.072347e-16
 6      A      Y     sd 0.58878406 -0.005074338 7.888294e-02
 7      B      X   mean 0.65000000  0.000000000 0.000000e+00
 8      B      X median 0.65000000  0.000000000 0.000000e+00
 9      B      X     sd 0.05773503  0.000000000 0.000000e+00
10      B      Y   mean 1.25000000  0.001000000 7.283065e-02
11      B      Y median 1.20000000  0.027500000 7.729634e-02
12      B      Y     sd 0.17320508 -0.030022214 5.067446e-02
```

Hopefully this is what you'd like to see!

---

If you want to then use the values from this dataframe a bit more, you can use other `dplyr` functions to select which rows in this table you look at. For example, to look at the bootstrapped standard error of the standard deviation of your measure for condition A / X, you can do the following:

```
bootresults %>% filter(cond=='A', comm=='X', term=='sd') %>% pull(std.error)
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Very good, but I think the bootstrap is not quite right for the specific repeated measures situation I have. Currently it's selecting by each `id` `cond` `comm` combination. This is better than selecting by row in the original `df`, but subtly different from selecting by `id` alone. Can your answer be modified to include `cond` and `comm` in the list along with `measure` so that each row in the modified `df` now corresponds to a single `id`?

Comment: I think it already is - at the moment what it does is summarise each repeated measure per `id`, but keep the separate rows for `cond` and `comm`. Then it groups the data by `cond` and `comm`, effectively making a new dataframe for each combination of the two factors. It then does a bootstrap for each of these four dataframes and resamples based on rows (once they are grouped, each subgroup only has 2 rows, one for each `id`.

Comment: Unless you want to make sure that on each bootstrap iteration the same group of subjects is resampled for each condition?

Comment: Ah, didn't spot that. I'm still pretty new to R, so I'll dive in an learn about the steps going on here. As long as the bootstrap is sampling on the basis of `id`, then the stats are calculated for all 4 `cond` x `comm` combinations then that is doing the right thing

Comment: Sorry if I've missed it, but `bootresults`just contains the stats, but not the 95% intervals. Would that just be a modification of `myfunc`?

Comment: Yes, that's what it's doing. It's initially a bit tricky to debug `dplyr` pipelines, but one good way to check the grouping works is to check how many rows per group it has: `df %>%  group_by(cond, comm) %>% count()`. This gives me 2 rows per group, and those will be the rows that `boot` resamples from inside the `do(tidy(...))` call. Effectively, by the time you've gone through `group_by(...) %>% do(tidy(...))`, the function inside the `do(tidy())` call only sees each group of the dataframe, rather than the whole entire dataframe.

Comment: @BenVincent you can get the confidence intervals out with the `tidy` function, see here: https://rdrr.io/cran/broom/man/boot_tidiers.html. I will update the answer with that (although note it throws an error with the small example data frame)

Comment: @BenVincent Just FYI, I ended up finding a bug in `tidy` and [opened an issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/broom/issues/230) to try and fix this.With this method, it's a bit hard to get the CIs right now, but definitely possible. I'll take another look at it later!

Answer (score 2):

For a bootstrap with a cluster variable, here's a solution without additional packages. I didn't use the `boot` package though.

**Part 1: Bootstrap**

This function draws a random sample from a set of clustered observations.

```
.clusterSample <- function(x, id){

  boot.id <- sample(unique(id), replace=T)
  out <- lapply(boot.id, function(i) x[id%in%i,])

  return( do.call("rbind",out) )

}
```

**Part 2: Boostrap estimates and CIs**

The next function draws multiple samples and applies the same `aggregate` statement to each of them. The bootstrap estimates and CIs are then obtained by `mean` and `quantile`.

```
clusterBoot <- function(data, formula, cluster, R=1000, alpha=.05, FUN){

  # cluster variable
  cls <- model.matrix(cluster,data)[,2]

  template <- aggregate(formula, .clusterSample(data,cls), FUN)
  var <- which( names(template)==all.vars(formula)[1] )
  grp <- template[,-var,drop=F]
  val <- template[,var]

  x <- vapply( 1:R, FUN=function(r) aggregate(formula, .clusterSample(data,cls), FUN)[,var],
               FUN.VALUE=val )

  if(is.vector(x)) dim(x) <- c(1,1,length(x))
  if(is.matrix(x)) dim(x) <- c(nrow(x),1,ncol(x))

  # bootstrap estimates
  est <- apply( x, 1:2, mean )
  lo <- apply( x, 1:2, function(i) quantile(i,alpha/2) )
  up <- apply( x, 1:2, function(i) quantile(i,1-alpha/2) )
  colnames(lo) <- paste0(colnames(lo), ".lo")
  colnames(up) <- paste0(colnames(up), ".up")

  return( cbind(grp,est,lo,up) )

}
```

Note the use of `vapply`. I use it because I prefer working with arrays over lists. Note also that I used the `formula` interface to aggregate, which I also like better.

**Part 3: Examples**

It can be used with any kind of stats, basically, even without grouping variables. Some examples include:

```
myStats <- function(x) c(mean = mean(x), median = median(x), sd = sd(x))

clusterBoot(data=df, formula=measure~cond+comm, cluster=~id, R=10, FUN=myStats)
#   cond comm mean median         sd mean.lo median.lo      sd.lo mean.up median.up      sd.up
# 1    A    X 0.85  0.850 0.11651125    0.85      0.85 0.05773503    0.85      0.85 0.17320508
# 2    B    X 0.65  0.650 0.05773503    0.65      0.65 0.05773503    0.65      0.65 0.05773503
# 3    A    Y 1.70  1.700 0.59461417    1.70      1.70 0.46188022    1.70      1.70 0.69282032
# 4    B    Y 1.24  1.215 0.13856406    1.15      1.15 0.05773503    1.35      1.35 0.17320508

clusterBoot(data=df, formula=measure~cond+comm, cluster=~id, R=10, FUN=mean)
#   cond comm  est  .lo  .up
# 1    A    X 0.85 0.85 0.85
# 2    B    X 0.65 0.65 0.65
# 3    A    Y 1.70 1.70 1.70
# 4    B    Y 1.25 1.15 1.35

clusterBoot(data=df, formula=measure~1, cluster=~id, R=10, FUN=mean)
#      est    .lo    .up
# 1 1.1125 1.0875 1.1375
```

Comment: Great work. For completeness, it's missing a `library(boot)` to access the boot function

Comment: Thanks for catching that. It's added.

Comment: This is great. But I'm trying to figure out if the bootstrap is doing sampling based on `id` in the original data frame. My novice eye suspects not, because `aggregate` is only passing `df$measure` as data to the `bootGroup` function, meaning that in `.bootStats` the selection is being done on rows, rather than actual `id`'s?

Comment: Your guess is correct: It does bootstrapping within groups. Specifically, `aggregate` splits the data by groups and then calls `bootGroup`, which returns bootstrap estimates and CIs for each combination of the grouping variables. Is this the desired behavior (or not)?

Comment: Close, but we really need to do bootstrap selection based on individuals, labelled as `id`. Would that require the `aggregate` function to be `bootGroup` function?

Comment: That makes sense. See my updated answer, and check if that does what you want. The new answer only base R because I don't know how to do clustered sampling with the `boot` package. In addition, the top-level function now uses formulas to control what `aggregate` does.