# Repeated measures bootstrap: resample per ID per condition

Tags: r, statistics, resampling, statistics-bootstrap

Having a hard time here... I'm trying to create 1000 bootstrapped data sets for each subject in a repeated measures design with three independent variables: DepthValidity (2 levels), SideValidity (2 levels), and TargetDepth (2 levels). An additional goal is calculating a bootstrapped reaction time mean, median, and sd for *each* subject, for *each* possible condition (there are eight conditions in total).

I tried using and manipulating the code as found here: [repeated measures bootstrap stats, grouped by multiple factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44927910/repeated-measures-bootstrap-stats-grouped-by-multiple-factors)

```
df <- mydata %>%
  group_by(ID, Depth, TarDepth, Side) %>%
  summarise(measure=list(ReactionTime)) %>%
  ungroup()

myfunc <- function(data, indices) {
  data <- data[indices,]
  return(c(mean=mean(unlist(data$measure)),
           median=median(unlist(data$measure)),
           sd = sd(unlist(data$measure))))
}
set.seed(333)
bootresults <- df %>%
  group_by(ID, Depth, TarDepth, Side) %>%
  do(tidy(boot(data = ., statistic = myfunc, R = 1000)))
```

My original data frame (i.e., mydata) is in long format, where each row corresponds to a *single* data point for an individual under one of the eight conditions. Each individual has approximately 90 data points per condition.

Using the code above, I get data with repeating values as seen highlighted here:
[image]

Are the identical values occurring because I need to execute the above code in a for loop  (i.e., for each unique ID)? I tried that and it didn't seem to work, but I may very well be doing something wrong there, too. Perhaps it's because I have to have a single column with all of the different combinations of conditions, rather than three separate columns? How do I prevent repetition?

EDIT: Included dput

```
dput(droplevels(head(individ, 20)))

structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "s109", class = "factor"), 
    TarDepth = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Mid", class = "factor"), 
    Side = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "DIFF", class = "factor"), 
    PRTS = c(0.834416149, 0.716587752, 0.716472204, 0.69970636, 
    0.699617629, 0.682915685, 0.666703417, 0.616733331, 0.599953582, 
    0.597570097, 0.595346526, 0.592605137, 0.588598339, 0.583834349, 
    0.58285897, 0.568965957, 0.567117837, 0.566593729, 0.566063329, 
    0.550269553), Depth = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "DIFF", class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT:
Included dput for *two* subject IDs, since I'm getting a bias and std.error of 0 according to commenter's most recent solution:

```
dput(droplevels(head(individ, 32)))

structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("s97", "s98"), class = "factor"), 
    TarDepth = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Mid", "Near"
    ), class = "factor"), Side = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("DIFF", 
    "SAME"), class = "factor"), PRTS = c(0.851425991, 0.84961243, 
    0.840487545, 0.839716775, 0.820657432, 0.815991426, 0.807378203, 
    0.800551856, 0.799805387, 0.787336857, 0.77253443, 0.765844159, 
    0.751196415, 0.749769895, 0.749374114, 0.649443255, 0.184844206, 
    0.608819523, 0.117052886, 0.082718123, 0.762629011, 0.050756321, 
    0.074764508, 0.147296557, 0.428583992, 0.432677868, 0.378136045, 
    0.135034201, 0.367393051, 0.593182243, 0.723897573, 0.533599005
    ), Depth = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("DIFF", "SAME"
    ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 32L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your data is showed in an image, which I cannot copy and test it.  I would recommend `dput` i.e. usage is `dput(droplevels(head(iris, 20)))` returns the structure of 20 rows

Comment: Thank you for your patience and continued help, @akrun. I edited my original question to include the `dput`

Comment: Please check my updated post.  It is just that your func didn't change the 'measure' to 'PRTS'

Comment: `nest_by` is from `dplyr`.   I am using `packageVersion('dplyr')#
[1] ‘1.0.6’`.  Please check your packageVersion of dplyr and if it is old, update it. thanks
>

Comment: Can you show `packageVersion('dplyr')`

Comment: Hi @akrun. So, I updated all of my R packages and `nest_by()` works fine now. I am not getting repeating numbers anymore under the "statistic" column, but I am not getting a bias and std.error of 0. I wonder if I should give you a `dput` with more than one subject ID... I will add a second edit.

Comment: Typo: I am getting a bias and std. error of 0.

Comment: Sorry, I am not understanding why you should 0 values.  The example works fine for me

Comment: @akrun I realized my mistake. I accidentally added an extra step... THANK YOU for your AMAZING guidance! Answer selected/upvoted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can split the data with `group_split` and loop over the `list`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)
set.seed(333)
bootresults <-  df %>%
  group_split(ID, Depth, TarDepth, Side)  %>%
  map_dfr(~ tidy(boot(data = .x, statistic = myfunc, R = 1000)))
```

---

Or another option is `nest_by`

```
set.seed(333)
bootresults <- df %>%
    nest_by(ID, Depth, TarDepth, Side) %>%
    mutate(new = list(tidy(boot(data = data, statistic = myfunc, R = 1000))))
```

#### Update

Using a reproducible example

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                  cond=c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'),
                  comm=c('X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y','X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y'),
                  measure=c(0.8, 1.1, 0.7, 1.2, 0.9, 2.3, 0.6, 1.1, 0.7, 1.3, 0.6, 1.5, 1.0, 2.1, 0.7, 1.2))
myfunc <- function(data, indices) {
    data <- data[indices,]
    return(c(mean=mean(unlist(data$measure)),
             median=median(unlist(data$measure)),
             sd = sd(unlist(data$measure))))
}
df1 <- df %>% 
   nest_by(cond, comm) %>% 
   mutate(out = list(tidy(boot(data = data, statistic = myfunc, R = 1000))))
df1
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Rowwise:  cond, comm
  cond  comm                data out             
  <chr> <chr> <list<tibble[,2]>> <list>          
1 A     X                [4 × 2] <tibble [3 × 4]>
2 A     Y                [4 × 2] <tibble [3 × 4]>
3 B     X                [4 × 2] <tibble [3 × 4]>
4 B     Y                [4 × 2] <tibble [3 × 4]>
```

Then, we `unnest`

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
      ungroup %>% 
      select(-data) %>%
      unnest(out)
# A tibble: 12 x 6
   cond  comm  term   statistic      bias std.error
   <chr> <chr> <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 A     X     mean      0.85   -0.000250    0.0555
 2 A     X     median    0.85    0.000900    0.0734
 3 A     X     sd        0.129  -0.0246      0.0362
 4 A     Y     mean      1.7    -0.00575     0.253 
 5 A     Y     median    1.7    -0.00650     0.374 
 6 A     Y     sd        0.589  -0.103       0.162 
 7 B     X     mean      0.65    0.000200    0.0258
 8 B     X     median    0.65    0.000550    0.0402
 9 B     X     sd        0.0577 -0.0120      0.0189
10 B     Y     mean      1.25    0.00260     0.0767
11 B     Y     median    1.2     0.0337      0.0995
12 B     Y     sd        0.173  -0.0372      0.0661
```

#### Update2

Based on the OP's input data, change the function 'myfunc' by changing the 'measure' with 'PRTS'

```
myfunc <- function(data, indices) {
  data <- data[indices,]
  return(c(mean=mean(unlist(data$PRTS)),
           median=median(unlist(data$PRTS)),
           sd = sd(unlist(data$PRTS))))
}
individ %>% 
   nest_by(ID, Depth, TarDepth, Side) %>%
   mutate(out = list(tidy(boot(data = data, statistic = myfunc, R = 1000)))) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   select(-data) %>% 
   unnest(out)
# A tibble: 3 x 8
  ID    Depth TarDepth Side  term   statistic      bias std.error
  <fct> <fct> <fct>    <fct> <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 s109  DIFF  Mid      DIFF  mean      0.630   0.000108    0.0166
2 s109  DIFF  Mid      DIFF  median    0.596   0.00756     0.0229
3 s109  DIFF  Mid      DIFF  sd        0.0738 -0.00361     0.0139
```

Comment: Hello akrun - thank you for taking the time to help me with this. I attempted your group_split and map_dfr method, and the data (mean, median, and mode) still repeats and now shows no bias/std.error from the boot, and the variable names (Depth, Side, TarDepth) and groupingID names are also missing.

I tried your nest_by, and keep getting errors as well. Also, did you mean nest_join or nest? Neither of those work as well.

Comment: @HannaHaponenko Can you post a dput of small example so that I can test it. thanks

Comment: So I ended up running map_dfr for every value in the list, and I ended up getting an error message

OUTPUT: Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default

Comment: @HannaHaponenko I requested `dput` so that I can test it and check where the error is. I meant the data and not the code.

Comment: @HannaHaponenko I added the reproducible example from the data in the linked post.  It is working fine for me

Comment: @HannaHaponenko i hope you have tested the updated solution.